# Find minimum amount of feature combinations reproducing certain coloring of objects

Tags: reference-request, dynamic-programming

## PROBLEM

Given a set of features $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m\}$.
You have a set of objects $X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ such that each object has certain combination of features. Some objects can have no features at all. Some other objects may have all of them. Two different objects may have same sets of features.

In addition the objects are painted in colors belonging to set $C = \{1, 2, \ldots, l\}$.

The input data might be visualized as in the following table:

```
+--------+-------------------------+-------+
| object |          features       | color |
|--------|-------------------------|-------|
|   1    | s1 = { a1, a2 }         |   1   |
|   2    | s2 = { a2, a5, a7 }     |   1   |
|   3    | s3 = { a1, a9 }         |   2   |
|   4    | s4 = { a8, a9, ... }    |   3   |
|  ...   | ........                |  ...  |
|   n    | sn = { a2, a15, ... }   |   1   |
+--------+-------------------------+-------+
```

where $s_k$ is a set of features assigned to object $x_k$.
In the other words $s_k \in S$ where $S = P(A)$, i.e. $s_k$ is an element of the power set of $A$.
We will also say that $c_k$ is color of object $x_k$.
 
Two different objects $k \neq j$ may have same color: $c_k = c_j$

You need to describe colors of objects via their features.

More precisely, you need to find the minimum possible subset $Q \subset P(A)$ such that:
$\forall k, j: c_k \neq c_j \implies q_k \neq q_j$ (objects of different colors must be described by different sets of features)
and
$\forall k: q_k \subset s_k$ (subset of features describing an object must be built only of the features assigned to the object).
where $q_k \in Q$.
Under minimum possible subset I mean subset with minimum cardinality $|Q|$. 
It is possible and even desirable that for some $k \neq j$ you have $q_k = q_j$.

You can assume that features are assigned in such a way that solution exists or you might design an algorithm which is able to detect cases when solution does not exist - whatever is more convenient.

## CONEXT

We have objects. User can supply them with meta-information (features) and modify some properties of them (colors). Our goal is to automatically build queries by features which would find appropriate objects and do the modifications same as user's. Thus we want to guess how user's work might be automated and provide him/her with re-usable ready solutions.

## QUESTION

Does anybody know an algorithm to solve the given problem?
Any references would be very welcome.
Or maybe you know the common name of this problem?

Comment: Smells like it might be NP-hard ... but perhaps you could try applying a SAT solver, if your problem size is small enough.